# Handling back key of an android phone in an angularjs application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a more-options button in my application which on clicking shows a list of options (which was hidden by default) and user can click on any of the options. Now when I press the hardware back-button of my phone, what I want is on the first click list should be hidden(if it is visible) and on second click user should be able to navigate to previous page.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(scope, next, current){
      if($('.popup-more').eq(0).css('display') === 'block'){
          $('.popup-more').eq(0).css('display','none');
              scope.preventDefault();
      }
      else{
          console.log("Pop up is already hidden.");
      }
});
```

the drawback with above code is preventDefault not only stops me to go to previous page directly if my list is displayed but it also stops me from navigating to the list items. I mean that's obvious because every time my display is block it will prevent redirection to a different page associated with list items.

I am using AngularJs for making the app.

Comment: You could move that listener to the <popup-more> Controller/Service (however you've designed it) so that when it opens, the listener is added and when you either select an item OR click the back button you remove the listener.

Comment: I placed the listener in the same controller. Selecting an item is not removing the listener possibly because when I click an item the locationChangeStart event in controller( which contains <popup-more>)  get's triggered and preventDefault will stop the navigation. So location will not change unless display is set to none. @kendavidson

Comment: Yes, if you are listening in the controller and clicking on links, this will happen.  But if you instead use `onClick="perform($selected)"` and in the perform function you remove the display from `<popup-more>` before doing a `$location.set($selected.href)` then you shouldn't have that issue.  My original comment was under the assumption that you had a `pageController` and `popupMoreController` and the listening was being done on the `popupMoreController`.

Comment: okay, thanks. I will try that and update you @kendavidson

Comment: So this wasn't working for hardware back-button, so what I did is I used a flag with  onClick function and setting it if display is block and then with the help of that flag I controlled locationChangeStart.  It works now. @kendavidson